# Syntax Error JSON file read with AJAX

Tags: ajax, json, syntax-error

I am getting a syntax error for the square bracket '[' from my JSON file. Given below is the JSON.

```
[

  {
    "Product Name":"CPE 10281",
    "Application":"Tyres",
    "Weight":150,
    "Cost to Produce":5000,
    "Grade":"A",
    "Cost to Sell":40000,
    "Strength":100
  },
  {
    "Product Name":"CPE 10282",
    "Application":"computers",
    "Weight":250,
    "Cost to Produce":4000,
    "Grade":"H",
    "Cost to Sell":25000,
    "Strength":90
  }
]
```

I am trying to use AJAX to read my JSON file.

```
                $.ajax({
                        url: "dataProductJSON.json",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        mimeType: "application/json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            var item = [];
                            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                                item.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
                            });
                            $('<ul/>', {
                                'class': 'interest-list',
                                html: item.join('')
                            }).appendTo('body');
                        },

                    });
```

I am running my html from Eclipse with Apache Geronimo as the server. 
Please Help.

Comment: That's valid JSON. Are you sure that's the problem? Could it be because you're attempting to extract a key and val from an array instead of the dicts within the array?

Comment: Hi Paul, Thank you for your comment. Sanjeev proposed an edit. It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `{` in the below line

```
success: function (data)
```

Make it

```
success: function (data) {
```

**Edit**

You are having parsing the data incorrectly , do it as below

```
     $.ajax({
                url: "test.html",
                dataType: 'json',
                mimeType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var item = [];
                    $.each(data, function (key, val){
                        $.each(val, function (innerKey, innerValue){
                            item.push('<li id="' + innerKey + '">' + innerValue + '</li>');
                        });
                    });
                    $('<ul/>', {
                        'class': 'interest-list',
                        html: item.join('')
                    }).appendTo('body');
                },

     });
```

You need to use 2 loop , one for the array and the other to loop through the object property

I tried things and it is working fine

Comment: I am sorry. I missed the { while pasting the code here. But despite that the error persists. Thanks for pointing that out Sanjeev.

Comment: Added a edit in answer, In case it's doesn't work let me know the error you are getting